# Export column from database table to text file

Tags: sql, vbscript

I have the code below, which copies the contents of a database table to a text file, but I want only one particular column of that table.

```vbs
Sub OnClick(Byval Item)                 
  Dim rs,fieldVals,dbConnIn
  Dim connectString,shell,tmp,fso,ts,line

  Const adOpenDynamic=2
  Const adLockPessimistic=2
  Const adCmdTable=2
  Const adOpenForwardOnly=0
  Const adOpenStatic=3
  Const adLockReadOnly=1

  'connectString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=192.168.168.4;Database=MYDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=myPassword;"
  connectString="Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=LocalServer;Initial Catalog=FOX_REPORTS"
  Set dBConnIn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  dBConnIn.CommandTimeout = 300
  dBConnIn.Open connectString
  ' This is just a simple way of getting a record set from and SQL Query
  Set rs=CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  rs.Open _
    "DATALOG", _
    dbConnIn, _
    adOpenStatic, _
    adLockReadOnly, _
    adCmdTable

  Set shell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set ts=fso.OpenTextFile("C:\DATALOG.TXT",2,True)
  line=""
  For Each tmp In rs.Fields
    line=line & tmp.Name & "    "
  Next
  ts.WriteLine Left(line,Len(line)-1)
  While Not rs.EOF
    line=""
    For Each tmp In rs.Fields
      line=line & """" & Replace(tmp.Value,"""","""""") & ""","
    Next
    ts.WriteLine Left(line,Len(line)-1)
    rs.MoveNext
  Wend

  rs.Close
  ts.close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```vbs
rs.Open _
  "DATALOG", _
  dbConnIn, _
  adOpenStatic, _
  adLockReadOnly, _
  adCmdTable
```

with

```vbs
rs.Open _
  "SELECT [colname] FROM DATALOG", _
  dbConnIn, _
  adOpenStatic, _
  adLockReadOnly
```

where `colname` is the name of the column you want to export.

Comment: And "adCmdTable" with (properly defined) "adCmdText". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Good point. Defaults should suffice here, though, so I simply removed the parameter.